# dynamodb,how to use primary key `in` sentence in query operation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to query a set of properties according to mutiple primary key.
e.g. I want to query two records using primary_key1 and primary_key2.
I used the KeyConditionExpression like this

`KeyConditionExpression: "primary_key in (:key1, key2)"
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
...
}`

but there is a mistake using in sentence in KeyConditionExpression.

The error I am getting is:

> Syntax error when use `in` sentence in KeyConditionExpression

How can I fix this?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It reported `invalid operator used in KeyConditionExpression: IN`

Answer (score 1):

The KeyConditions doesn't support `IN` operator. Also, it doesn't support `OR` operator.

However, it does support `AND` operator to filter the data by hash key and sort key.

> For KeyConditions, only the following comparison operators are
>   supported:
>
> EQ | LE | LT | GE | GT | BEGINS_WITH | BETWEEN
>
> KeyConditionExpression — (String) The condition that specifies the key
>   value(s) for items to be retrieved by the Query action.
>
> The condition must perform an equality test on a single partition key
>   value. The condition can also perform one of several comparison tests
>   on a single sort key value. Query can use KeyConditionExpression to
>   retrieve one item with a given partition key value and sort key value,
>   or several items that have the same partition key value but different
>   sort key values.

You can **scan** rather than query using FilterExpression. However, please be aware that scan is a costly operation in DynamoDB which may not be the solution you are looking for.

```
var params = {
        TableName: "Movies",    
        FilterExpression: "title IN (:titlevalue1, :titlevalue2)",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":titlevalue1": "The Big New Movie 2012",
            ":titlevalue2": "The Big New Movie",

        }
    };
```

The other option is to query the database multiple times using different keys.